# Async compression c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, compression

i have this code

```
  string dirName = "C:\\temp";

        if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
        {

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Файлы:");
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName);

            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                string sourceFile = $"{s}"; 
                string compressedFile = $"{s}z";

                Compress(sourceFile, compressedFile);
            }

        }
```

it shows me all files in directory and compress it.
method compress:

```
 public static void Compress(string sourceFile, string compressedFile)
    {

        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {

            using (FileStream targetStream = File.Create(compressedFile))
            {
                using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(targetStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    sourceStream.CopyTo(compressionStream); 
                    Console.WriteLine("Compressing file {0} is end. : {1}  compressede size is: {2}.",
                        sourceFile, sourceStream.Length.ToString(), targetStream.Length.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i do async compression of this files? should i use array of tasks? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make Compress async method

   ```
   public static async Task Compress()
   {
       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
          //your compress logic 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call it as awaitable: `await Compress(...)`;
   You can also use `Parallel.ForEach` instead of your `foreach` loop.

But be aware that this code won't really execute in parallel. This is because that you are using IO functions.